# Angular 2 unit test code inside subscribe()

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-observables

I have the following method

```
protected create (): void {
    this.projectService.getPartsList(this.project.id, this.project.versionId).subscribe((geometry: Geometry) => {
      this.projectService.createNewProject({
        data: {
          parts: [ geometry.data.parts ]
        },
        importedVersions: [{
          assetClass: '3dgeometry',
          versionId: this.project.versionId
        }],
        modelOfferingId: this.project.modelOfferingId,
        name: this.projectName
      });
    });
  }
```

and the following unit test: (Note ProjectService is using a mock class that returns spys for all methods in it)

```
  describe('create()', () => {
    it('should call getPartsList from projectService and then call createNewProject when the resolves passing the payload', () => {
      let payload: any = {
        data: {
          parts: []
        },
        importedVersions: [{
          assetClass: '3dgeometry',
          versionId: ''
        }],
        modelOfferingId: '',
        name: 'Test Project'
      };
      modalCreateAdvancedInstance.projectName = payload.name;
      modalCreateAdvancedInstance.project = {
        modelOfferingId: '',
        versionId: ''
      };
      modalCreateAdvancedInstance.create();
      expect(projectService.getPartsList).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(projectService.createNewProject).toHaveBeenCalledWith(payload);
    });
  });
```

The `createNewProject` method is never called because the `getPartsList` method just returns a spy and doesn't call `.subscribe()`. How do I mock this up so that getPartsList returns an observable that calls .subscribe.

Comment: `getPartsList` spy should return `Observable.of(mockedGeometry)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: That did it. :)